# What is the Laplace transform transfer function of affine expression $\dot x = bu + c$?

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

For the one dimensional case, with $a, b, c$ being real constants, $u$ being the system input, $x$ the state, what is the Laplace transfer function of:

$$\dot x = bu + c$$

Ideally I'm looking for an expression $X(s)/U(s)$, but I don't know if this can be done with that additive constant $c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the expression you're looking for as this system has no transfer function because it is not a linear system, i.e. it does not satisfy the [additivity property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity#In_mathematics).

Assuming zero initial conditions for $x$, you have

$$sX(s)=bU(s)+\frac{c}{s}$$

from which you can't get an independent transfer function $H(s)=X(s)/U(s)$.

Comment: Say I wanted to create a classic feedback system with a reference signal to track. Then could it make sense to model c as a disturbance added to u before the plant?

Comment: @JDS: Yes, then your input signal would be the sum of the original signal and the noise, and your system would be linear with a transfer function (w.r.t. to the new noisy input).