# Transfer function of differential equation

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

I'm trying to find out the transfer function of simple differential equation:
   $$a_0\dot y + a_1y=b_0x+b_1$$
The problem is i have no idea what to do with $b_1$.
If we apply the Laplace transform then we will have
$$a_0sY(s) + a_1Y(s)=b_0X(s)+b_1/s$$
The problem is that i have to reach $X(s)/Y(s)$ .

[What is the Laplace transform transfer function of affine expression $\dot x = bu + c$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157994/what-is-the-laplace-transform-transfer-function-of-affine-expression-dot-x-b?rq=1)
 Based on this we do not have a solution?

Comment: What would you do without the $b_1$. It is good if you show some effort. Do you know what a transfer function is?

Comment: without $b_1$ it would be $$b_0/(a_0*s+a_1)$$ i think

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is to introduce a new variable $\bar{x}(t) := x(t) + \frac{b_1}{b_0}$. This would enable you to express the transfer function by means of $\bar{X}(s)$, at least:

$$ \frac{\bar{X}(s)}{Y(s)} = \frac{a_0s+a_1}{b_0}. $$